# How to calculate the stress-energy-momentum tensor of a field that leads to finite volume with infinite extension?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, curvature

Let's assume a theoretical spherically symmetric metric which leads to a finite volume with infinite extension.
The metric is characterized by

1. $$\mathrm{d}s^2=-B\,c^2 \mathrm{d}t^2+A\,\mathrm{d}r^2+r^2 \mathrm{d}\Omega.$$ (the general spherically symmetric metric)

and

2. for $r\rightarrow\infty$, the square root of the curvature parameter $A$ decreases at least with $1/r^3$
   (to allow for finite volume with infinite extension)

How can the stress-energy-momentum-tensor be calculated that leads to this metric?

My thoughts on that:

1. As the volume is finite, the stress-energy-momentum-tensor should be finite as well.
2. In the derivation of the Schwarzschild metric, $B$ is given by $B=1/A$ - but I'm not sure whether this applies here or not.
3. Somehow the next step would be to put the metric into the left hand side of
   $$ R_{\mu\nu} - \frac12 g_{\mu\nu} R = \frac{8\pi G }{c^4} \langle T_{\mu\nu}\rangle$$
   and calculate $T_{\mu\nu}$...

Comment: Related post: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/701716/

Comment: Why the brackets around $T_{\mu\nu}$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unorthodox way of solving Einstein field equations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/483259/168783)